# Python: Import comma separated data from a TXT file

Tags: python, csv, import, txt, raspberry-pi-pico

I built a data logger with a Raspberry Pi Pico. The Data Logger saves the temperature every six minutes in the TXT file.
I am currently failing to import the data from the TXT file into Python.

The data looks like this:
`1,20.5,2,21.0,3,21.0,4,21.0,5,21.0,6,21.0,7,21.0,...`

The data set thus contains two variables, which are separated by commas, an incrementing counter and the temperature with one decimal place. The dataset has about 240 measurements.

So far I have tried different methods to import the data. I have turned the TXT file into a CSV file and tried importing as a dataframe using pandas:

`temp_df = pd.read_csv('temp_data.csv', header=None)`

This gives me a df with one observation and a three-digit number of variables. I cannot import the dataset to have only two variables and about 240 observations.

I also tried to import the data as lists:

```
import csv 
file = open("temp_data.csv", "r")
temp_list = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))
file.close()
print(temp_list)
```

Which results in the error:
`"TypeError: 'list' object is not callable".`

--> All in all, I need a solution that uses the TXT file directly and creates a df.
I am still very inexperienced with Python and hope for your help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, post the full traceback you get, verbatim

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15780/510848478.py in <module>
      2
      3 file = open("temp_data.csv", "r")
----> 4 temp_list = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))
      5 file.close()
      6

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: It looks like you override `list` in your code. Do you use `list` as name somewhere in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
import pandas


data = dict()

with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        splitted = line.split(",")
        data = {**data, **dict(zip(splitted[::2], splitted[1::2]))}

as_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame({"counter": data.keys(), "temperature": data.values()})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try pd.read_fwf. It is for reading fixed width format.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html

Comment: OP does not work with fixed-width file

Answer (score 0):

I would use numpy here. Numpy are python lists with nice functionalities. They allow you to save/retrieve the list in a .npy file.

eg.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [1,20.5,2,21.0,3,21.0,4,21.0,5,21.0,6,21.0,7,21.0]
data_numpied = np.array(data,dtype=float)
np.save("numpy_data_storage.npy",data_numpied,allow_pickle = True)

# Restart / exit here

new_data = [42,42,1.0]
old_data = np.load("numpy_data_storage.npy",allow_pickle=True)
new_data2 = np.concatenate((old_data,new_data))

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(new_data2,columns = ["Temperature"])
```

However, the ".npy" file is not human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

Given the input file

```
1,20.5,2,21.0,3,21.0,4,21.0,5,21.0,6,21.0,7,21.0`
```

as example, try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('temp_data.csv', header=None)
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.iloc[0,0::2].astype(int).values, data=dict(temp=df.iloc[0,1::2].values))
print(temp_df)
```

Result:

```
     temp
1  20.5
2  21.0
3  21.0
4  21.0
5  21.0
6  21.0
7  21.0
```